# Kernel appears to have died, it will restart automatically

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I run the script below, a message pops up saying that the kernel appears to have died and that it will restart automatically. Could it be due to one of the RData files I am using being 450 MB in size?

```
import pyreadr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df_FaultFree = pyreadr.read_r('TEP_FaultFree_Training.RData') 
df_Faulty = pyreadr.read_r('TEP_Faulty_Training.RData')
DF = pd.concat([df_FaultFree,df_Faulty])
normal_data =DF[ (DF['faultNumber']==0)].iloc[:,3:] 
normal_data_table = pd.DataFrame(normal_data)
print(normal_data_table)
```